# How to use login_redirect with a user capability

Tags: plugins, redirect, login

The following code should redirect the user to a specific page if they have the manage_woocommerce capability or higher - but it doesn't and just goes to the main dashboard.

```
    add_filter( 'login_redirect', array( $this, 'login_redirect' ), 10, 3 );
    public function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {

        if( is_user_logged_in() == 1 ) {

            if( $user->has_cap( 'manage_woocommerce' ) ) {

                $redirect_to = get_admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=my-page';

            }

        }

        return $redirect_to;

    }
```

I have tried `$user->has_cap`, [current_user_can](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) with the same result.

Comment: Do you use WordPress Multisite?

Comment: And... Where did you add that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it wasn't easy to catch, but... There is one major problem in your code...

First check you make is:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() == 1 ) {
```

And `is_user_logged_in()` is based on global `$current_user` variable. But... As you can read in [`login_redirect` hook docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect):

> The $current_user global may not be available at the time this filter
>   is run. So you should use the $user global or the $user parameter
>   passed to this filter.

So this condition won't be satisfied - so your code won't change anything.

You should use `$user` variable that is passed as param, so this should do the trick:

```
public function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {

    if ( is_a ( $user , 'WP_User' ) && $user->exists() ) {

        if ( $user->has_cap( 'manage_woocommerce' ) ) {

            $redirect_to = get_admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=my-page';

        }

    }

    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', array( $this, 'login_redirect' ), 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but you're calling the `is_user_logged_in()` function too early. It will only work after another page load. So here's a simplified and efficient version to achieve the functionality:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', array( $this, 'login_redirect' ), 10, 3 );

public function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user )
{
    if ( $user instanceof WP_User && user_can( $user, 'manage_woocommerce' ) ) {
        $redirect_to = get_admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=userexplorer-userify';
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}
```